# Updating User profile resets password even if no new password is entered with Laravel 9 and Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

When updating a User profile, password is being reset even though a new password is not being entered.  Existing password should be retained if no new one is entered.

**livewire/user/edit.blade.php**

```html
...
<div class="mt-6 flex flex-row gap-x-4 border border-gray-200 p-6 bg-gray-50">
    <div class="basis-1/4">
        <label for="new_password" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
            New Password
        </label>
        <div class="mt-1">
            <input wire:model="new_password" type="password" name="new_password" id="new_password"
                    autocomplete="new-password"
                    class="shadow-sm focus:ring-orange-500 focus:border-orange-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
        </div>
        @error('new_password')<span
            class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <div class="basis-1/4">
        <label for="new_password_confirmation" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
            Confirm Password
        </label>
        <div class="mt-1">
            <input wire:model="new_password_confirmation" type="password" name="new_password_confirmation" id="new_confirmation"
                    class="shadow-sm focus:ring-orange-500 focus:border-orange-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

**Livewire/User/edit.php**

```
...
class Edit extends Component
{
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $new_password = '';
    public $new_password_confirmation = '';
    public $role;


    public function mount(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->first_name = $user->first_name;
        $this->last_name = $user->last_name;
        $this->email = $user->email;
        $this->password = $user->password;
        $this->role = $user->role;
    }

    public function updateUser($id)
    {
        $record = User::find($id);

        $this->validate([
            'new_password' => ['confirmed'],
        ]);

        $record->update([
            'first_name' => $this->first_name,
            'last_name' => $this->last_name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'role' => $this->role,
            'password' => bcrypt($this->new_password) ? : $record->password,
        ]);

        session()->flash('success', 'User Successfully Updated');

        return redirect()->route('user.edit', $record->id);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user.edit');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes first,

- Livewire has a `$rules` property that you should use, and declare the rules separately - see https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation
- Instead of doing `updateUser($id)` and then `$record = User::find($id);`, you can just do `updateUser(User $user)` through "model route binding"
- You may want to update the current user instead, so update `$this->user` instead of fetching it again through the parameter

Your actual issue though, instead of updating all properties at once, move the array to a variable, and then push the password only if it was changed.

```php
$userData = [
    'first_name' => $this->first_name,
    'last_name' => $this->last_name,
    'email' => $this->email,
    'role' => $this->role,
];

if (filled($this->new_password)) {
    $this->validate([
        'new_password' => ['confirmed'],
    ]);

    $userData['password'] = bcrypt($this->new_password);
}

$record->update($userData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your setting $new_password to an empty string.

`public $new_password = '';`

But you evaluate whether it’s null in your updateUser method.

I would start by setting `public $new_password = null;`

Then in updateUser update your new_password check to:

`'password' => $this->new_password ? bcrypt($this->new_password) : bcrypt($record->password),`

You could also leave the property set as empty string and check for `empty($this->new_password)` but I prefer the null route.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a simple `if` there to be more explicit, but if you prefer a quick, inline solution to your problem then this should do:

```php
'password' => bcrypt($this->new_password ?: $record->password),
```

Comment: thank you, but that is what I have and it’s not working.

Comment: that's not what you have in the code you pasted ^
Have you tried? ;)